# UBUNTU: sudo apt-get update HTTPS redirect

Tags: apt

The sudo apt-get update command is failing because the URL present in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudera-cdh5.list is having https instead of http.

So I have introduced a command to replace the https url with http.

Is there a way we can automate this and make sure sudo apt-get update automatically handles https redirects ?

Comment: Error Observed: 
sudo apt-get update 
Hit us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main amd64 Packages 
Err archive.cloudera.com precise-cdh5/contrib Sources 
HTTP response code said error